# Writing a sum-of-squares function or SIR model fits

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, systems-biology

I am trying to write a function that calculates and returns the (sum-of-squares) value (SSQ) for the fit of a simple SIR model, parameterized with given values of $\beta$ and $\gamma$, to any dataset.
and then I want to use the following parameters.

- $\beta$ = 1.15, $\gamma$ = 0.02
- $\beta$ = 1.7, $\gamma$ = 0.45

This is the code I have written so far.

But I can't get the desired results shown at the end nor can I create the graph

```
*total size of population*) n = 763;

(*days*)
tmax = 14;

(*Flu dataset*)
numberinfected = {3, 8, 26, 76, 225, 298, 258, 233, 189, 128, 68, 29, 
   14, 4};
(*Set parameter values*)
{\[Beta], \[Gamma]} = {1.15, 0.02}; 

(*Define the SIR model equations*)
sireqns = {s'[t] == -\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n, 
   i'[t] == \[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Gamma]*i[t], 
   r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t]};

initialConditions = {s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0};

(*Solve the differential equations*)
sol = NDSolve[{sireqns, initialConditions}, {s, i, r}, {t, 0, tmax}];

(*Extract the infected values from the solution*)
infectedValues = i[t] /. sol[[1]];

(*Calculate the sum-of-squares (SSQ) value*)
ssq = Total[(infectedValues - numberinfected)^2];

(*Print the SSQ value*)Print["Sum-of-Squares (SSQ) value: ", ssq]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIniM.png) "ssq = 2507764.33057048, where beta = 1.15, gamma = 0.02"

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTqyF.png)"ssq = 4630.302259291, where beta = 1.7, gamma = 0.45"

[image]

Comment: when I did `Plot[infectedValues, {t, 0, tmax}]` I do not get same plot you show, ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ls6S.png)  so something is wrong with your model or input it seems to me.  I am assuming the plot you show is for `infectedValues` which you called `i` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing the last little bit:

```
(*Extract the infected values from the solution*)
infectedValues = i /. sol[[1]];

(*Calculate the sum-of-squares (SSQ) value*)
ssq = Norm[infectedValues[Range[tmax]] - numberinfected]^2;
(*Print the SSQ value*)
Print["Sum-of-Squares (SSQ) value: ", ssq]

(*Sum-of-Squares (SSQ) value: 2.51677*10^6*)
```

Upon plotting the data and the fit, we see the fit does not capture the behavior of the data very well:

```
pointsPlot = 
  ListPlot[numberinfected, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed"];
fitPlot = Plot[infectedValues[t], {t, 1, 14}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[pointsPlot, fitPlot, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Using the other parameter values = 1.7, = 0.45 produces much better results (`ssq = 4686.73` compared to `ssq = 2.51677*10^6` previously)
[image]

**Add-on** I don't know if you need this, but we can also find the best $\beta$ and $\gamma$ values using `ParametricNDSolve`. I would have loved to use `NArgMin` with my objective function `objective` but it was giving me issues, so I just did a brute force search for the minimum `ssq` for $0\leq \beta \leq 2$ and $0 \leq \gamma \leq 1$:

```
(*total size of population*)
 n = 763;

(*days*)
tmax = 14;

(*Flu dataset*)
numberinfected = {3, 8, 26, 76, 225, 298, 258, 233, 189, 128, 68, 29, 
   14, 4};
ClearAll[\[Beta], \[Gamma]]
sireqns = {s'[t] == -\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n, 
   i'[t] == \[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Gamma]*i[t], 
   r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t]};

initialConditions = {s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{sireqns, initialConditions}, {s, i, r}, {t, 
    0, tmax}, {\[Beta], \[Gamma]}];

(*Extract the infected values from the solution*)
infectedValues = i /. sol;

objective[b_, g_] := 
 Norm[(infectedValues[b, g][Range[14]] - numberinfected)]^2
bDom = Range[0, 2, 0.01];
gDom = Range[0, 1, 0.01];
res = Flatten[Table[{b, g, objective[b, g]}, {b, bDom}, {g, gDom}], 1];
Flatten[res[[PositionSmallest[res[[All, 3]]]]]] // Most

(*{1.67, 0.44}*)
```

Comment: I have just seen your update. That is so useful. Thank you !!!!!!

Comment: Although when ```data = {{10, 19}, {17, 4}, {24, 5}, {32, 47}, {36, 38}, {38, 54}, {41,84}, {42, 55}, {47, 116}, {50, 102}, {52, 126}, {58, 153}, {59,164}, {62, 172}, {63, 177}, {67, 142}, {68, 158}, {69, 151}, {75,155}, {80, 125}, {81, 116}, {84, 101}, {87, 106}, {88, 116}, {94, 85}, {98, 59}, {102, 67}, {105, 57}, {114, 59}, {117, 24}, {118, 
    39}, {120, 31}, {128, 36}, {134, 8}, {140, 7}, {142, 3}, {147, 
    20}, {150, 7}, {155, 2}, {159, 25}, {163, 2}, {186, 10}, {191, 
    17}, {200, 7}};  timeValues = data[[All, 1]]``` but I don't know what to put in  ```Range[]```

Comment: ```objective[b_, g_] := 
 Norm[(infectedValues[b, g][timeValues] - numberinfected)]^2
bDom = Range[0, 2, 0.01];
gDom = Range[0, 1, 0.01];
res = Flatten[Table[{b, g, objective[b, g]}, {b, bDom}, {g, gDom}], 1];
Flatten[res[[PositionSmallest[res[[All, 3]]]]]] // Most``` i found it